# Modifying Request Validation for Lightswitch WCF RIA Services

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services, ria, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a VS2010 Lightswitch application which uses a number of services which I've developed in a separate DLL and added to the application as WCF RIA Services.

My problem is that some of these service calls include string parameters that can contain angled brackets which are illegal for the default request validator.

I cannot seem to disable this request validation. I've tried all of the following without success:

1) Setting requestValidationMode="2.0" in the ServerGenerated web.config ()
2) Setting a custom requestValidationType in the WCF RIA DLL's app config ()

What's peculiar is that when I use Fiddler, I don't even see a call being made to the service. It is as if the lightswitch client is intercepting the call.

Everything works fine if I just replace the parameter that contains the angled brackets with one that does not.

Comment: if you upgrade to LightSwitchV2 (VS2012), does the problem still exist?